# How to open Port 9 permanently?

Tags: networking, 14.04

I want to know how to open port 9 permanently for wake on lan purpose. Currently I've tried using `iptables -A INPUT -p udp -sport 9 -j ACCEPT`, but it is giving me following error: `Bad argument 9`. Any solution regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Your command would be:

`iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 9 -j ACCEPT`

See here for more info on iptables: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks, it is not giving error. But http://www.canyouseeme.org/ is still showing that my port 9 is not open.

Comment: @MayankLal I'm out of my depths here, but does "canyouseeme.org" use udp traffic in it's test, or ip? Just a thought.

Comment: @MayankLal you can use nc (nc -v -z -u -w 5 serverip port-number) to check for open udp port.

Comment: @Nischay I just ran the command, but it didn't show any output

Comment: @MayankLal check for the exit status of nc if it is 1 then port is not open. echo $?. Also try to use it without -w option. for more information check man page for nc

Comment: @Nischay Should I use internal IP or external IP for serverip?